# Sum of multiplication of non intersecting elements in a matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

Is there any formula for sum of multiplication of non-intersecting elements in a matrix?

For example for a $3\times 3$ matrix 
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} &a_{12} &a_{13}\\
a_{21} &a_{22} &a_{23}\\
a_{31} &a_{32} &a_{33}
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
I am looking for

$a_{11}\Big(a_{22}a_{33}+a_{23}a_{32}\Big)+a_{12}\Big(a_{21}a_{33}+a_{23}a_{31}\Big)+a_{13}\big( a_{21}a_{32}+a_{22}a_{31}\Big).$

This looks like the determinant formula except that it doesn't change sign.

Comment: Looks like you want the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent) of the matrix.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't know the name!